# REST Assured: how to test object of type "Set" in body?

Tags: java, rest, rest-assured

I would like to get assert the response body using REST Assured. But currently I am not able to do so. I am getting the below-mentioned error message.

Implementation detail is as follows :

```
BannerDto resultBannerDto = given()
            .contentType("application/json")
            .body(bannerAddDto)
            .when()
            .post("/api/v1/admin/banners")
            .then()
            .statusCode(HttpStatus.OK.value())
            .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
            .body("name", equalTo("banner A"))
//this line make error:
            .body("regions", equalTo(regionsSet.toString()))
            .extract().as(BannerDto.class);
```

while error is:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
JSON path regions does not match.
Expected: [1, 2]
Actual: [1, 2]
```

parameter regionsSet is:

```
    private Set<Long> regionsSet = new HashSet<>();
    regionsSet.add(1l);
    regionsSet.add(2l);
```

and Response of the Service is as follows:

`{regions=[1, 2], endDate=2017-05-01T22:00:00, productIds=[], bannerId=15,...`

Comment: add the full expected response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is pretty simple after looking into your response body. What you are trying to do :

```
.body("regions", equalTo(regionsSet.toString()))
```

here is collecting the data of `regions` from response body which is currently a JsonArray and comparing it with string due to which your case is failing. Here below I have given a little code which will clarify your issue. Over here I am using Gson Library :

```
public class Simple {

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        Set<Long> regionsSet = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        regionsSet.add(1l);
        regionsSet.add(2l);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        JsonArray jr = new JsonArray();
        jr.add(1);
        jr.add(2);
        System.out.println("Not Equal now : " + jr.equals(gson.toJson(regionsSet).toString()));
        System.out.println("Equal now :  " + jr.toString().equals(gson.toJson(regionsSet).toString()));
    }
}
```

Sample output :

```
Not Equal now : false
Equal now :  true
```

Hope this clarified your problem and made you understand how to proceed.